# Why can't I explicitly cast some data types like string to int, byte, float, etc? C#

Tags: c#, casting

I know that it's impossible to cast `string` or `bool` like `(int)MyString` `(short)MyBool` and so on while it's allowed to cast `int` to `short`.

Unfortunately I could not find explanation, why. So I'm asking it here.

Why is not allowed explicitly cast some data types (I am not asking how to convert string to other types or something like this)?

Comment: Because they contain different kinds of data?  It also has to do with languages like C# having strict type-safety rules.

Comment: For the obvious reason of "how do you define a `string` as an `int`?".

Comment: @ColeJohnson First of all, simply want to know why. Secondly, I think it would be more readable if I could explicitly cast every data type.

Comment: @PLB: That's exactly the nightmare we came out of in languages like BASIC.  You want to go back to that?

Comment: "(I am not asking how to convert string to other types or something like this)" But your example is one of casting a string to an int...?

Comment: It was a conscious decision by the language designers. Are you looking for reasons for that decision?

Comment: @BoltClock It was for example.

Comment: @MattBall Yes, I am looking for reasons for that decision. From answer of Niranjan Kala, I guess why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer: [Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

> Explicit conversions (casts): Explicit conversions require a cast
>   operator. Casting is required when information might be lost in the
>   conversion, or when the conversion might not succeed for other
>   reasons.  Typical examples include numeric conversion to a type that
>   has less precision or a smaller range, and conversion of a base-class
>   instance to a derived class.

From: [Explicit Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s682k58%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Explicit conversion is required by some compilers to support narrowing
>   conversions. It is a language-specific way to perform conversion. In
>   some languages, like C# and C++, explicit conversion is performed
>   using casting. Casting occurs when you prefix a conversion with a data
>   type that defines the type of the conversion you want to perform. In
>   Visual Basic, the CType function is used to allow explicit conversions
>   of data types that are not allowed implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

This is a decision the language designers made to force the programmer to choose how to make the conversion.

Consider this string to int: `"4.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"`.  What should the Int32 answer be? `4` or `5`?

Consider this string to date conversion: `"5/8/12"`.  In the US, this would be `May 8th`, while in the UK, it would be `August 5th`.

- [Implicit casts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) exist where there would be no loss of precision.
- [Explicit casts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) exist where there is a safe conversion (with no risk of misunderstanding the data), but some precision information may be lost.
- Conversions exist for the remaining cases, such as string to int, bool, date, etc.

Comment: However, an execption may be thrown if the value is out of constraint of the "cast-to" type

Comment: Unfortunately, Java chose backward rules for its floating-point types, and .net followed suit.  Conversion from `double` to `float` should be widening because, for every `double`, there is one `float` value which is either the unambiguously-correct representation, or is within a part per quadrillion of being the unambiguously-correct representation.  By contrast, for almost any non-NAN `float` value, there are many millions of `double` values it could represent.  Even (float)INF could represent (double)1E+39, 6E+100, or billions of other values besides (double)+INF.